# python html form library that supports forms within form (form as a field )?

Tags: python, forms, form-processing

The question says it all,

For example,

In a contact book if someone has multiple addresses with each address having multiple fields I want to display an "add another address" button.  This button would add another address form. (I want one round trip to the server, I do not want javascript or webforms2.)

It would be nice if some built in library would support this.  Examples are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [django-formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/), and if you want dynamic behavior use this http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/